# Textile Formatting in Redmine wiki pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine, wiki, textile

I use Textile markup in Redmine to format my wikipages.

Redmine Version is 1.3.0
Mongrel Server
Rails 2.3.14

When I enter

```
h1. Wikis

h2. Creating a new wiki page

Laleu

h2. Creating a new wiki page

Laleu

h2. Creating a new wiki page

Laleu
```

I get the following result

[image]

the html of this is

```
<div class="wiki wiki-page">
  <a name="1"></a>
  <h0 wikis="">1<a href="#1" class="wiki-anchor">¶</a></h0>


  <a name="2"></a>
    <h0 creating="" a="" new="" wiki="" page="">2<a href="#2" class="wiki-anchor">¶</a></h0>
<p>Laleu</p>
<a name="2"></a>
    <h0 creating="" a="" new="" wiki="" page="">2<a href="#2" class="wiki-anchor">¶</a></h0>
<p>Laleu</p>    
    <a name="2"></a>
    <h0 creating="" a="" new="" wiki="" page="">2<a href="#2" class="wiki-anchor">¶</a></h0>
<p>Laleu</p>
  </div>
```

Does anyone got the same problem?

I didn´t find anything about this problem on the Redmine wiki pages.

Thanks! Matthias

Comment: I found out that there is a side effect with the 

[Post Link Plugin][1]

I will inform the developer


  [1]: http://code.google.com/p/redmine-post-link-plugin/

Comment: Matthias, add this as answer.